# Following cursor in dynamic UITextView with UITableView no longer working in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uitextview

I created a `UITextView` which is sized dynamically within a `UITableViewCell` as a person types.

On iOS 10 the `UITextView`'s cursor is followed automatically with very little code needed.

In the `UITextViewDelegate` method `textViewDidChange:` I've used this code which updated the size of the text view without any jumping around.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    self.tableView.contentOffset = currentOffset
}
```

In iOS 11 this no longer works and when I type the cursor disappears under the keyboard. Note that I didn't need any changes when the keyboard appeared.

I know that there were changes in iOS 11 related to how content insets work but have been unable to figure out what changes I'd need to make to make this work.

Where should I be looking to make these changes to fix it?

**-- Update --**

It would turn out that removing all of that code solves my problem in iOS 11 and iOS 11 handles scrolling down to follow the cursor as I type automatically without any problems.

The one issue I have remaining is that I can only type up to 28 lines of text into the UITextView before it stops updating the UITextViews size.

Comment: have you set the number of lines in this textView to be equal to zero?

Comment: can you provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Have your tried with textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0. This will give no limit to number of lines

Comment: @BrunoFulberWide I didn't see that as an option in IB.

Comment: @ThanhPham Besides the above code the rest is a UITableView with a UITextView in one of the cells. The UITextView is pinned to the cell sides with a greater than or equal height constraint. There is no other custom code than what you see above so there isn't anything else I have to provide.

Comment: @manismku It's not so much that I can't get more lines. It's that the UITextView doesn't resize dynamically as the content of the text view changes. I will give your suggestion a try however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the same problem, a UITableViewController with a UITableViewCell containing a non-scrolling editable UITextView in a cell, and the cursor would go behind the keyboard in iOS11. Worked fine in prior iOS versions.

I finally figured out a fix based on this and other articles:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    // handle to UITableView
    UITableView *tableView = ....

    // tell table to resize itself
    [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }];

    // get the caret rectangle so we can make sure we scroll it into view.
    CGRect unconvertedRect = [textView caretRectForPosition:textView.selectedTextRange.start];
    CGRect caretRect = [textView convertRect:unconvertedRect toView:tableView];
    // make the rect a little bigger so it's not at the extreme bottom of the view area
    caretRect.size.height += caretRect.size.height / 2;

    // this doesn't seem to work with a simple dispatch_async, but dispatch_after 0.1s seems to work.
    // why, i have no idea.
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [tableView scrollRectToVisible:caretRect animated:NO];
    });
}
```

Hope this helps someone...

Comment: This is what fixed it for me on iOS 11.  Thank you.

Comment: It works but there is still short jump effect because of this 0,1 sec.

Answer (score 3):

From XCode 9, the calculation of row is automatic once you set properties in size inspector of tableview.[Here, You can check this in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVshu.png)
and I mad one change in `func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)`
Below is my code

```
 func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
        textView.sizeToFit()
    }
```

and It's working fine for me in iOS 11

[image: Here is Image of my tableview from storyboard,] you can see constraints as well, which are simple and I am using it without margins.

And your textview cursor issue, I would suggest you [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager), it will manage all things like this.

Comment: Thanks for this one. I gave it a try and its not working for me still. Could you share your constraints for auto layout with this set up please?

Comment: To confirm, when I type in to the UITextView with this set up the cursor disappears under the keyboard so if you've got something to fix that can you share that also please?

Comment: I have updated my answer, check it out. I hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
class TextViewTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var textView: UITextView! {
        didSet {
            textView.delegate = self
            textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        }
    }

    var textDidChangeHandler: (((text: String?, shouldScroll: Bool)) -> Void)?

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let size = textView.bounds.size
        let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: size.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))

        let shouldScroll = size.height != newSize.height ? textView.text.count == textView.selectedRange.location : false
        textDidChangeHandler?((text: textView.text, shouldScroll: shouldScroll))
    }
}
```

Inside you data source `cellForRow` method:

```
// dequeue TextViewTableCell cell
cell.textDidChangeHandler = { [weak self] (text, shouldScroll) in
    guard let this = self else { return }
    // do whatever actions with text if needed
    guard shouldScroll else { return }
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates() 
    }
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
}
```

Also good to have minimum height constraint for text view (for e.g. >=44)

Comment: I have tried this and didn't have any luck with it. I see some scrolling happening but once the text goes below the keyboard level the tableview scrolls down a little and then bounces back to the top.

Comment: @MarkReid well, maybe in this case you're settings your tableView contentInset to wrong value? My example is related to UITableViewController, which handles tableView insets by default.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I too am just using UITableViewController unmodified for this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the sabe method to update a textView, and it's working fine for more than 28 lines of text, make sure you have all this properties set:

```
textView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

also when i define the textView text i call `textView.sizeToFit()`

Comment: Hi, these are all set in my app currently and I'm still getting the same issue, but thank you for the response.